# How to send a keyboard event to a different Window in Pywin32?

Tags: python, pywin32

I have to write a script to emulate some keyboard event in a different program in background.This is my code：

```
pwin = win32ui.FindWindow(None,r'someprograme')
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,18)
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,68)
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYUP,18)
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYUP,68)
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,13)
pwin.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYUP,13)
```

But it seems nothing happened.So what should i do?I've tried PostMessage func it seems it still can not do it.

Comment: First, are you sure `pwin` is the right window? Second, does it have keyboard focus? Third, why aren't you passing both params? (I haven't checked the docs yet; maybe 0 is always appropriate for the lparam?) Finally, what keys are those? (You know you can't use `WM_KEYDOWN` for most uses of `ALT`, right?)

Comment: Also, what app are you trying to drive?

Comment: it seems i do not got the right window.I want to send an ALT+D to a program to open sth. So if WM_KEYDOWN can not be used how could i send it?

Comment: For your first point: If you don't have the right window, none of the other stuff matters; you obviously have to get the right window first, or you can't even test things out.

Comment: For the second: Why do you want to send Alt+D to the program? What are you trying to open? Normally this would pop open the first menu in the menubar with an underlined "D" in the name. Is that what you're trying to do? If so, see my answer, where I explain why it won't work in many apps, and what to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the [WM_KEYDOWN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a nonsystem key is pressed. A nonsystem key is a key that is pressed when the ALT key is not pressed.

But looking up [your keycodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you're trying to send ALT-D (followed by ENTER, which is fine). It sounds like you're trying to drive the menus; if that's what you want to do, `WM_KEYDOWN` is not the way to do it.

The problem is that keyboard menu navigation is driven by Windows, not by the app (except for a handful of apps that override normal menu processing, like some versions of Visual Studio). When you're looking at Notepad, and you hit ALT-F to open the File menu, the Notepad code gets a bunch of menu-related messages (`WM_INITMENU`, etc.), not the keystrokes.

If you use a WM spy program (I think the free Visual Studio Express still comes with Spy++ and ManagedSpy, but if not, search for an equivalent), you can see what the application is actually seeing when you drive it with the keyboard, and then you can figure out how to emulate that from your Python script.

On top of everything else, depending on how the program is written, it may not accept keystrokes when it doesn't have focus.

By the way, if you're just getting started with Windows GUI automation, you might want to look at something higher level, like [`pywinauto`](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/). That way, you don't have to work out what menu-related messages to send to open the Data menu; you just do something like `app.Foo.MenuSelect('Data')`.

Comment: thanks,i've used pywinauto to finish the task.When use sendkeys instead of the keyevent, it works